# getting all the misspelled words in gtktextview while using gtkspell

Tags: gtk

How can i get all the texts which are misspelled on gtktextview

so that i can put those on container and use for future actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that directly in GtkSpell. You could try searching the text buffer for any text with a tag that has its `"underline"` property set to `PANGO_UNDERLINE_ERROR`.